# How to make .position-sticky stop below another angular component (navbar)?

Tags: angular, sass

I have a container that I want to always stay on the screen so I used `.position-sticky` class. However, problem is part of it is goes behind the navbar when scrolling. How can I prevent this? I'm new to angular so I don't know how to change this without affecting the rest of the site. Thanks

Here is my container in my component:

```
<div class="container my-container px-md-3 px-0">
  <div class="content py-lg-4">
    <div class="row m-0">
      <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 px-0 pr-md-6">
        <nav class="menu position-sticky rounded-edge p-0 mb-4 mb-lg-0 w-100 mx-md-0">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column bg-white rounded-edge w-100">
            <li class="nav-item px-0 px-lg-4 py-3 section-header rounded-top d-none d-lg-block">
              <h2 class="text-dark font-weight-bold px-0 m-0">Menu</h2>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item px-4 px-lg-4 py-1 active-section-link" >
              <a class="nav-link text-dark" >
                Introduction
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item px-4 px-lg-4 py-1">
              <a class="nav-link text-dark">
                Body
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item px-4 px-lg-4 py-1 rounded-bottom">
              <a class="nav-link text-dark">
                See more
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And it's scss:

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/functions',
'~bootstrap/scss/variables',
'~bootstrap/scss/mixins/breakpoints';
@import '~sass/globals';

.position-sticky {
   position: fixed !important;
   top: 20px; //doesn't work
   left: 0;
   z-index: 1030;
   margin: 0;
   width: 100% !important;
    
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

usually I solve this by adding a navbar to my `app-component.html` and a container for all content. The navbar will be fixed at top position and the content container is placed beneath.

Here is an expample:

```html
<nav></nav>
<div class="contentContainer">
 YOUR CONTENT or `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
</div>
```

```css
nav {
  height: 40px;
}

.contentContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: You are right, my information wasn't complete, it was more of an idea how to solve your problem. Here I made an example to show you how it's working: https://jsfiddle.net/ky345urz/